# How to send DTMF in Linphone ios SDK

Tags: swift, xcode, linphone, linphone-sdk

Calling functionality is working fine but the SendDTMF isn't working. Here is my minimal code that can help to understand the situation.

```
class AnswerCallViewController: UIViewController {
var call: Call!
var proxy_cfg: ProxyConfig!
    
let coreManager1 = LinphoneCoreManager()
var lc: Core?
let coreManager2 = LinphoneCoreManager2()
var mIterateTimer: Timer?
var cPtr: OpaquePointer?

 @IBAction func btnsAppend(_ sender: UIButton) {
            
    let digit1 = sender.currentTitle!
    print("digit1", digit1)

    let cchar = (sender.currentTitle!.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)?[0])!

    do {
       try call?.sendDtmf(dtmf: cchar)
    } catch {
        print("DTMF failed because \(error)")
    }
}
```

It's should work but it's always return error. The error log is -

```
liblinphone-warning-linphone_call_send_dtmf(): invalid call, canceling DTMF
sendDtmf and Returns: -1 on error.
```

Other Information -

```
Linphone SDK - Version 5 (compiled  with g729 codec.)

Xcode - Version 12.4 (12D4e)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like call is invalid.

Comment: Yes, do you have any idea how it will be resolved?

Comment: According to source code, it simply means your call pointer is null.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you call is defined and call.state == .StreamsRunning